# When I click Random it shows [object object] instead of Array Data

Tags: javascript, arraylist

The code stores data from form and displays them in list ,      When I click random it should show random values from array but it doesn't , It shows [object object] and the random values should not repeat

```
 <form >
        First Name<input id = "name1" required/> 
        Last Name <input id ="name2"  required/> 
        City <input id ="city"  required/>
        </form>

          <button onclick="getResult()" >SUBMIT</button>
          <button onclick="getData()">Random</button>
        <br><br>
    <p id="store"></p>
        <br>
        Random Data:<output id="info"/>
        <h3>Student Data </h3>
        <output id="out"/>



        <script>

        var arr=[];
        function getResult(){
        var name1 = document.getElementById('name1').value;
        var name2 =document.getElementById('name2').value;
        var city = document.getElementById('city').value;
        var students={
        firstName:name1,lastName:name2,cityName:city
        }
        arr.push(students);
        var k='';
        for(var g=0;g<arr.length;g++)
        k=k+" <li>"+eval(g+1)+'.'+arr[g].firstName+" "+arr[g].lastName+" "+arr[g].cityName+"       </li>";
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = k;
        document.getElementById('name1').value="";
        document.getElementById('name2').value="";
    document.getElementById('city').value="";
     document.getElementById('store').innerHTML='Number of students = ' +arr.length +'';
    }



    function getData(){
    var rand = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];  
    var el=document.getElementById('info')
    el.innerHTML=rand;

    }



        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the following solve:

```js
var arr=[];
var arrForRnd = [];
function getResult(){
  var name1 = document.getElementById('name1').value;
  var name2 =document.getElementById('name2').value;
  var city = document.getElementById('city').value;
  var students={
    firstName:name1,lastName:name2,cityName:city
  }
  arr.push(students);
  arrForRnd.push(students);
  var k='';
  for(var g=0;g<arr.length;g++)
    k=k+createLi(g, arr[g]);
  document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = k;
  document.getElementById('name1').value="";
  document.getElementById('name2').value="";
  document.getElementById('city').value="";
  document.getElementById('store').innerHTML='Number of students = ' +arr.length +'';
}

function createLi(g, studentInformation) {
  return " <li>"+eval(g+1)+'.'+studentInformation.firstName+" "+studentInformation.lastName+" "+studentInformation.cityName+"       </li>";
}



function getData(){
  if(arr.length == 0){
    return;
  }
  if(arrForRnd.length == 0){
    for(loop = 0 ; loop < arr.length; loop++) {
      arrForRnd.push(arr[loop]);
    }
  }
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrForRnd.length);
  var el=document.getElementById('info');
  el.innerHTML=createLi(rand, arrForRnd[rand]);
  arrForRnd.splice(rand, 1);
}
```

```html
<form >
        First Name<input id = "name1" required/> 
        Last Name <input id ="name2"  required/> 
        City <input id ="city"  required/>
        </form>

          <button onclick="getResult()" >SUBMIT</button>
          <button onclick="getData()">Random</button>
        <br><br>
    <p id="store"></p>
        <br>
        Random Data:<span id="info"></span>
        <h3>Student Data </h3>
        <span id="out"></span>
```

Comment: Yes this helps but how not to repeat the result

Comment: @UmarSatti: Can you elaborate what you mean by not to repeat the results?

Comment: I mean if there are 5 values and one clicks 5 time all 5 values should be different and random

Comment: @UmarSatti: The edited code should serve the purpose. The random values are refreshed after all the possible values are exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `object` because you have pushed `object` into array and you are getting back `object` from `array`. So you need to get properties from `object` and show them in `div`.

```
function getData(){
    var rand = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];  
    var el=document.getElementById('info')
    el.innerHTML=rand.firstName;
}
```